# When translating universal affirmatives should we use implication or conjunction?

Tags: logic, language

Sometimes, when translating a sentence like "All dogs are animals", I often see it represented like this:

```
(∀x)(Px ⊃ Qx)
```

However, I feel like the following is also a good translation:

```
(∀x)(Px ∧ Qx)
```

Why do I always see this represented with 'implication' instead of 'and'?

```
Dictionary:
Px = x is a dog
Qx = x is an animal
```

Comment: Because the second way forces every object to be a dog (and an animal). It's a very common mistake.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. What if you said:
(∀x)(Px ∧ Qx);

(∀y)Qy

Comment: Forall x(Px and Qx) implies Forall x(Qx), which is identical to Forall y(Qy), modulo the useless change of the bound variable x to y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will shamelessly use the opportunity to talk about the distinction between *[unrestricted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier#Logic)* vs *[bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier)* *quantifiers*. I suspect our intuitions favor one or the other in different contexts, causing the confusion.

When quantifiers are introduced in logic courses they're usually *unrestricted*, which means that the x in ∀<sub>x</sub> and ∃<sub>x</sub> ranges over the entirety of the domain of discourse. An alternative is to have *bounded* quantifiers ∀<sub>x ∈ A</sub> and ∃<sub>x ∈ A</sub> for every subset A of the domain of discourse. The confusion might be arising because the universal quantifier in "all dogs are animals" is implicitly taken to be a bounded one:

> (1) ∀<sub>x ∈ Dogs</sub> ( Animal (x) ).

Then, since the standard quantifiers are unrestricted, the thought is to express the same idea with this:

> (2)* ∀<sub>x</sub> ( Dog (x) ∧ Animal (x) ),

where Dog(x) is meant to play the role of specifying the subdomain x is supposed to range over. But as I already mentioned in the comments, (2)* will be true iff the whole domain of discourse consists only of dogs, while (1) will be true in every domain where dogs are animals. The 'solution':

> (3) ∀<sub>x</sub> ( Dog (x) → Animal (x) ),

other than being the right translation for (1) using *unrestricted* quantifiers, is an instance of a general pattern called *[guarded quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification#Range_of_quantification)*, which has the following form:

> (Guarded Quantification) ∀<sub>x</sub> ( φ → ψ ).

The φ acts as a "guard" for ψ, meaning that the truth of ψ is tested only for those x in the domain that satisfy φ. In sum, guarded quantification, of which (3) is an instance, is a method of achieving restricted quantification in a language with only unrestricted quantifiers and an unstratified domain of discourse.